# Datadog RUM add region/country

Tags: angular, datadog

Hello I am new with Datadog. I am adding a RUM in my UI like this:

```
<script>
  (function(h,o,u,n,d) {
     h=h[d]=h[d]||{q:[],onReady:function(c){h.q.push(c)}}
     d=o.createElement(u);d.async=1;d.src=n
     n=o.getElementsByTagName(u)[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(d,n)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.datadoghq-browser-agent.com/datadog-rum-v4.js','DD_RUM')
  DD_RUM.onReady(function() {
    DD_RUM.init({
      clientToken: 'myClientToken',
      applicationId: 'myAppId',
      site: 'datadog.com',
      service: 'my-web-application',
      env: 'dev',
      version: '1.0.0',
      sampleRate: 100,
      sessionReplaySampleRate: 100, // if not included, the default is 100
      trackResources: true,
      trackLongTasks: true,
      trackInteractions: true,
    })
  })
</script>
```

Is there a way I can add a variable in the *DD_RUM.init* to specify the country

> country: 'us'

I assume I will need to add different scripts files for each country and environment (dev,prod)

'us' > dev,prod

'mx' > dev,prod

... etc

and then be able to filter the view given the country

I would like to start with adding the country. However if you could provide further hints or links with examples that would be great

Thank you!

Country:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some context around what you are trying to achieve with this? The Datadog Browser SDK already collects the country that the user is accessing your application from. You can read more about the [RUM Browser Data Collected](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/data_collected/) in the docs.

If you are looking to segment something based on some other country designation that you decide at runtime, you may be able to leverage [global context properties](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/modifying_data_and_context/?tab=npm#global-context)

Comment: in the project we are working with different locations, eg. America, Europe, Asia. It makes sense what you say, but I don't see any country displayed on the RUM (I have attached an image). The idea to add a variable with the location ... to show/filter by region, If I am in the US, then is America ... But I think fist I would like to display the country to see it works, then switch it to the Location

Comment: First, I would make sure you are you using a time scale that has active user sessions during it, if you are and it's still showing no location information, we need to see if IP addresses are being collected because location information is computed from the session's IP address. You can check to see if IP addresses are present in your RUM events by going to a Session Replay and checking the Attributes tab. Under Session, you should see the Country, City, etc. from the session - if you don't you can look at the JSON view and see if `session.ip` exists.

Comment: @EricAllen Thank You Eric, it took me some time to understand, it should pick up the IP, since I am calling the web within the company, the IP is an internal IP (that's why nothing is showed). So Country it should work, what I would like to ask you, is there a way in the init section, to add a new String Value?

Comment: You could use [global context properties](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/modifying_data_and_context/?tab=npm#global-context) or the [beforeSend](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/modifying_data_and_context/?tab=npm#enrich-rum-events) event to modify the event's context.